# Pass email between subdomain

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

This is a how to question as I don't know where to start. It would be great if someone could recommend an article/tutorial.

I have two domains, app.mydomain.com and mydomain.com.

mydomain.com - is the landing page of the site. On the landing page I collect the users email using a form and then forward the user on to the registration page of app.mydomain.com

I would like to store the email I collect on mydomain.com and enter it into the registration form email field on app.mydomain.com

app.mydomain.com - is built using meteor js and meteor-accounts.

mydomain.com - is a static site, built using middleman.

I would attempt to try something if I knew where to start. Can someone recommend some reading or tutorials to help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple to do this. Let's say that on your static site, you can do it one of three ways:

1) You put the registration form on your meteor site, made to look like it belongs on your main site, when you click on the menu item, it just switches to that site.

2) You make the action of the form the meteor site, so it processes the request. You need to do a little work to make sure the cross site permissions are allowed

3) You make the form processing (in middleman) save the data directly to the meteor mongo database

If the two virtual hosts are on the same server this is a little easier, but not impossible

Comment: Hi Mikkel, thanks for the suggestions. I host the static site on an amazon s3 bucket and the app is hosted on metoer galaxy. Registration is complete on the app the static site just collects an email. Is there a way to pass just the email collected on the static site across to the app.

Comment: You can use lambda functions with AWS S3 buckets to connect to your Mongo database and save it there.